# Is there a Photoshop plug-in that reduces PNG file size using pngcrush?

Tags: plugins, adobe-photoshop, png

I’ve used [pngcrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/) to reduce the size of PNGs produced by Photoshop. It’d be neat if there was a plug-in for Photoshop that ran pngcrush automatically on PNGs when saving them for the web.

Is there such a thing? Is such a thing possible? (I don’t know what limits there are on what Photoshop plug-ins can do.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two such options:  One free and one payware

SuperPNG is freeware
PNGoutwin is payware

Better yet use R.I.O.T. albeit not from within photoshop.  No interwebs access required per use.

Comment: As far as I can tell, PNGoutwin isn’t a Photoshop plugin. But [SuperPNG](http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/) looks great.

Answer (score 1):

No there's no such plugin for Adobe Photoshop. Why don`t you use [Smush.it](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/smushit/) ?

Comment: Looks worth comparing with pngcrush. It’d be nice to have something baked into the Photoshop saving workflow.